# how to write this this long equation?

Tags: equations, programming, subequations

```
  \begin{align}\nonumber
(A_{1}^{5}+A_{8}^2)\tt_{m}^{2}\k^{2}P_{m}^{5}-\left(2(A_{1}^{2}+A_{2}^2) 
(\Delta_{a}-\omega_{m}\chi^{2}C)\omega_{m}\chi^{2}-2J^{2}\omega_{m}\chi^{2} 
(\kappa_{a}A_{2}-\Delta_{d}A_{1})\right)P_{m}^4\\
\nonumber
   &&+((\kt_{a}A_{1}+J^{2}\om_{d})^2+ 
   (\kappa_{a}A_{1}+J^{2}\Delta_{d})^2+ 
   (\Delta_{a}-\omega_{m}\chi^{2}C)^2(A_{1}^{5}+A_{7}^2)+2J^{2}(\Delta_{a}- 
    \omega_{m}\chi^{5}C)(\Delta_{d}A_{1}-\kappa_{a}A_{9}))P_{m}^2\\
\nonumber
&=&\left|\x_{0}\right|^{2}(m_{1}^{2}+n_{2}^5)+2\kp_{0}A_{2}gJ\S
Cos[m]N+J^{2}gk^{2}S^{2}N^{2}
\tag{M1}
    \end{align}
```

Comment: please extend your code fragment to small, self contained document, which have define `\k` . Do you really need `\S` symbol in equation or you give it some new meaning? What is Cos?Just  three variables? Your question is unclear.

Comment: What is your document class? Which font size? Do you use the standard layout?

Answer (score 1):

Since you not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete document which we can test as it is), we haven't any information about your document layout, used packages relevant to your equation and about eventual defined new commands or math operators.

Also is not clear, why you require that part of equation use `\tt` fonts (btw, correct is `\ttfamily`) and what means in your equation  symbol `\S` (section sign)  in your equation (usually used in legal documents). Further, which coding you use (where is define `\k` symbol)

With use of standard `article` document class, fonts `newtxmath`, packages `mathtools` and `nccmath`, and breaking your equation into four lines I managed to obtain the following result:

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\tag{M1}
    \medmath{
 \begin{aligned}
\bigl(A_{1}^{5}
+ & A_{8}^2\bigr)_{m}^{2}k^{2}P_{m}^{5} - 
        \Bigl(2\bigl(A_{1}^{2}+A_{2}^2\bigr)
        \bigl(\Delta_{a} - \omega_{m}\chi^{2}C\bigr)
        \omega_{m}\chi^{2}-2J^{2}\omega_{m}\chi^{2}
        \bigl(\kappa_{a}A_{2}-\Delta_{d}A_{1}\bigr)\Bigr)P_{m}^4    \\
+ & \Bigl(\bigl(kt_{a}A_{1}+J^{2}om_{d}\bigr)^2+
        \bigl(\kappa_{a}A_{1}+J^{2}\Delta_{d}\bigr)^2 +
        \bigr(\Delta_{a}-\omega_{m}\chi^{2}C\bigl)^2
        \bigl(A_{1}^{5}+A_{7}^2\bigr)                               \\
+ & 2J^{2}\bigl(\Delta_{a} - \omega_{m}\chi^{5}C\bigr)
        \bigl(\Delta_{d}A_{1}-\kappa_{a}A_{9}\bigr)\Bigr)P_{m}^2    \\
= & \abs{x_{0}}^{2}\bigl(m_{1}^{2}+n_{2}^5\bigr) + 
        2kp_{0}A_{2}gJ\S
        Cos[m]N+J^{2}gk^{2}S^{2}N^{2}                                         
    \end{aligned}
            }
\end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `MWE` having some errors, e.g., `\k`, `\kt`, etc. I just removed just `\` for compiling purpose, and the modified codes are given below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

 \begin{align}\nonumber
(A_{1}^{5}+A_{8}^2)\tt_{m}^{2}k^{2}P_{m}^{5}&-\left(2(A_{1}^{2}+A_{2}^2) 
(\Delta_{a}-\omega_{m}\chi^{2}C)\omega_{m}\chi^{2}-2J^{2}\omega_{m}\chi^{2} 
(\kappa_{a}A_{2}-\Delta_{d}A_{1})\right)P_{m}^4\\
&\quad\nonumber
  +((kt_{a}A_{1}+J^{2}om_{d})^2+ 
   (\kappa_{a}A_{1}+J^{2}\Delta_{d})^2+ 
   (\Delta_{a}-\omega_{m}\chi^{2}C)^2(A_{1}^{5}+A_{7}^2)\\
&\quad\nonumber+2J^{2}(\Delta_{a}- 
    \omega_{m}\chi^{5}C)(\Delta_{d}A_{1}-\kappa_{a}A_{9}))P_{m}^2\\
&\nonumber
=\left|x_{0}\right|^{2}(m_{1}^{2}+n_{2}^5)+2kp_{0}A_{2}gJ\S
Cos[m]N+J^{2}gk^{2}S^{2}N^{2}
\tag{M1}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Note that, I've break the equations per standard format...

Comment: You could use `align*` (starred form) so that adding \nonumber is not needed

Comment: @user94293 But the `OP` is giving the equation number as `M1` as in `\tag` command in the last set of equation...

Comment: In this case the simplest is to use  an `equation` environment, and inside, insert `\begin{aligned}[b]`.

Comment: @Bernard Agreed your statement, really that's the nice way, shall I change my answer?

Comment: No problem if you want  to, but there's something else: if the margins are the standard margins, there's an `overfull \hbox` message.

Comment: @Bernard I too noticed that, but the `OP` doesn't provide his `preamble`, so I'm not sure about the `OP's` textwidth, so only I ignored it...